# Top space to superview does not work

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, constraints, uinavigationbar

I want to set an `UIImageView` under the `NavigationBar` like Twitter profile.
I create a constraint on the top of the `UIImageView` to superview but it does not work, the `UIImageView` display below `NavigationBar`.
Why ?

**Storyboard :**

[image: From storyboard with the constraint]

**Screen :**

[image: result]

**Code :**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

**Constraints :**

[image: constraist of imageview]

Comment: Please also include your auto layout constraints in the question.

Comment: What is the end result you want?

Comment: A result like Twitter profile : http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Twitter-apps-on-profile-pages.png

Comment: Try removing under top bars and customize your UI in storyboard and check

Comment: Are those constraints on your "city" image? Or on the "circle" image? Or on both?

Comment: Only city image.

Comment: Hmm... seems like something else is going on. Why doesn't your "gear" button show up?

Comment: Because is black !

Comment: The "gear" button looks white in your Storyboard image... Try setting the `.backgroundColor` of your View to `.red` and see if the black bar changes to red (which it should).

Answer (score 1):

Along with your code

[image]

Add the following line of code:

**self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have your view controller extend under the navigation bar. You can do this in the storyboard like shown:

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: All are enables.

Comment: @MichelRobico does the parent view have Clips To Bounds set to false?

Comment: The UIImageView clipsToBounds is true, but parent is false.

Comment: @MichelRobico try to set `self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear`

Comment: Nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background color of your navigation bar doesn't seem to actually set it to clear, it's not an issue with the constraints.

I had the exact same problem, try the following code inside viewDidLoad instead.

**Swift**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

**Obj-C**

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage: [[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think view controller property `Under Top Bars` is disable.

[image]

Enable this property as shown in above figure and your problem will solve.

Comment: Under Top Bars is enable.